# How to Bind and Display a Collection in a Data list or Grid View

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, listbox

I have three classes for my page. Products are displayed on the page and are added to the basket.

The added products are displayed in a list box through a listbox.

I cannot figure out how to bind and display the collection in a data list or grid view so I have more control over the layout and any additional functionality I might like to add.For example adding removing items etc.

Here are the classes:

```
public class Product
{
    public string ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public string ImageFile { get; set; }
}

public class CartItem
{
    public CartItem() {}

    public CartItem(Product product, int quantity)
    {
        this.Product = product;
        this.Quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public void AddQuantity(int quantity)
    {
        this.Quantity += quantity;
    }

    public string Display()
    {
        string displayString = 
            Product.Name + " (" + Quantity.ToString()
            + " at " + Product.UnitPrice.ToString("c") + " each)";
        return displayString;
    }
}


public class CartItemList
{
    private List<CartItem> cartItems;

    public CartItemList()
    {
        cartItems = new List<CartItem>();
    }

    public int Count { get { return cartItems.Count; } }

    public CartItem this[int index]
    {
        get { return cartItems[index]; }
        set { cartItems[index] = value; }
    }

    public CartItem this[string id]
    {
        get {
            foreach (CartItem c in cartItems)
                if (c.Product.ProductID == id) return c;
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static CartItemList GetCart()
    {
        CartItemList cart = (CartItemList) HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"];
        if (cart == null)
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] = new CartItemList();
        return (CartItemList) HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"];
    }

    public void AddItem(Product product, int quantity)
    {
        CartItem c = new CartItem(product, quantity);
        cartItems.Add(c);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        cartItems.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        cartItems.Clear();
    }
}
```

On my page, the products are displayed in a datalist from the database. Binding is done through sqldatasource.

This is the add method which adds the product to the listbox and simply adds and displays the string returned from the display() method in the class.
I'd like to figure out how to display the items in something like a label control etc.

```
protected void add(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Product p = new Product();
    LinkButton BuyNowButton = (LinkButton)sender;
    DataListItem item = (DataListItem)BuyNowButton.NamingContainer;
    Label IdLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("productidLabel");
    Label NameLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("productnameLabel");
    Label ValueLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("productpriceLabel");
    p.ProductID = IdLabel.Text;
    p.ProductName = NameLabel.Text;
    p.ProductPrice =Convert.ToDecimal(ValueLabel.Text);

    CartItemList cart = CartItemList.GetCart();
    CartItem cartItem = cart[p.ProductID];
    //if item isn’t in cart, add it; otherwise, increase its quantity
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBoxQuantity");
    int quantity = Convert.ToInt16(tb.Text);
    if (cartItem == null)
    {
        cart.AddItem(p,quantity);
        total += Math.Round(p.ProductPrice * quantity, 2);
    }
    else
    {
        cartItem.AddQuantity(quantity);
        total += Math.Round(p.ProductPrice * quantity, 2);
    }

    displayList();
}
```

And here is the method that displays the basket:

```
protected void displayList()
{
    CartItemList cart = CartItemList.GetCart();
    CartItem item;

    for (int i = 0; i < cart.Count; i++)
    {
        item = cart[i];
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item.Display());
    }

    Label3.Text = "Total : " + total.ToString();
}
```

How do I display my data from either database or something like an arraylist on my page in a way that is very customizable as in add "addquantity" "remove" "display message once order total is over certain amount etc."?

So far I've just been binding it to gidviews or datalists or listboxes but that doesn't quite let me present it the way I would like to.

What's happening behind the scenes at websites basket ordering systems such as here https://takeaway.nandos.co.uk/Menu/Appeteasers

Comment: Using a [repeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) allows you tight control over the HTML used for each item in the repeater.

Comment: aps table is what i was looking for all my life. thanks